# Spring MVC @Async limiting task

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I am trying to implement a feature in a Spring MVC app that kicks off a long running job. The task will be kicked off by a Spring Controller. Since it could take a long time to finish (few mins to over an hour), @Async seems to be a perfect candidate for what I am trying to do.

One requirement is that, I want to limit async task per id. To explain the problem statement. Lets say we need to build a student report for a given student id. Controller will kick off a reporting job for given id. At any given time only one report can be run for a given student id.

If a new request comes in, if there is a report running for that id, we want to cancel that and start a new job (Assuming new request will provide the most up to date info and old request is no longer relevant). Reporting task can run for different ids (eg. job for student id 100 and 200 can run but only one task per id should run at a time.. ie. there should not be two jobs for id 100).

Here is how the controller would look like:

```
@RequestMapping("/report/{id}")
.. ...
Future<Void> reportFuture = reportService.generate(id)
.....
```

Service would looks similar to:

```
@Async
public Future<Void> generate(int id) {
 ... Do some Long Calculations generate a report
}
```

So, how can we keep track of the async task such that we know if there is a job running for given id, if so cancel that?

Comment: You would have to store the `Future` in some shared map with the corresponding ID. If a new request comes in for that same id, you can cancel the future. You will probably need to implement your `@Async` method with some interruption mechanism.

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis, for clarifying, thats exactly is the point of my question. What is the best way to store Future. If I put in session, it will only be applicable per user session. There could be multiple users.

Comment: You could put it in the `ServletContext` or create a singleton bean that holds a map of them. Careful with that though, you don't want a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis, ServletContext might be perfect solution for me given it needs to hold it temporarily while the report is being generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by creating a singleton scoped component that would track the report. When the service call is being made, it would first check the component to see if there is a `Future` for the given id. If not, it would add the `Future` in that component and start the process. If the component returned a `Future`, it would call cancel on that `Future` and start a new service call.